# What are time-based fields that Facebook Graph API uses to filter result set when including SINCE and UNTIL parameters on /videos endpoint?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When retrieving data from the /videos API endpoint using the SINCE and UNTIL parameters, what are the time-based data fields that the API is using to filter the result set?

In the example below, I am retrieving videos from July 28th through July 30th, but a video in the result set was created and last updated on August 2nd and there is a video published on July 29th that is excluded:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/8429246183/videos?since=2017-07-28&until=2017-07-30&fields=created_time,updated_time&access_token=[token]

This is the only documentation I have found that discusses the SINCE and UNTIL parameters and that only says that they represent "a Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the [start/end] of the range of time-based data."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

Comment: A bug report has been sent to Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/857977471031534/ And a post was added to the Facebook Developer group: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/1496449587065217/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has stated in the [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/857977471031534/) submitted on this issue that the SINCE and UNTIL parameters filter on an unpublished field based on the time that a video draft was originally created or scheduled. While this is not the ideal behavior, they have said that they do not currently have plans to correct this in the immediate future.